# Visual Studio no detecta contexto de la Base de datos ERROR CS0246

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, conexión

Visual studio dejo de detectar el contexto de mi base de datos

```
private MiSistema db = new MiSistema ();
```

me marca error en MiSistema, el error es es el error CS0246 ( No se pudo encontrar el tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres 'tipo/espacio de nombres' (¿falta una directiva de uso o una referencia de ensamblado?) )

al revisar mi Web.config la cadena de conexión existe y no ah sido modificada

Comment: lee tu error, dice que algún using te falta. Lo más seguro, es que MiSistema no esté importado en la clase donde lo quieres instanciar

Comment: no le falta ningun Using el proycto funcionaba bien, levo ya un tiempo con el y este error aparece incluso en controladores que no eh tocado por semanas, lo que si hice fue crear un cambio en mi base de datos un campo nuevo en una tabla no se si esto genero alguna modifcacion o corrupcion en mi modelo ya probe cambiar el webconfig con uno de una version de respaldo y no funciona

Comment: Proba limpiar y recompilar todo

Comment: Quita una Referencia y vuelve a ponerla (cualquiera)

Comment: ya lo intente y nada, investigando me di cuenta que por alguna razon no contaba con la carpeta `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Entity Framework Tools\NuGet Packages` lo que hice actualizar y restaurar mi visual studio desde el instalador del IDE y me genero la carpeta con los archivos correspondientes espero sirva por si alguien tiene el mismo problema Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 0):

Investigando un poco más a fondo me di cuenta de que, por alguna razón, no contaba con la carpeta `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Entity Framework Tools\NuGet Packages`. Lo que hice fue actualizar y restaurar mi Visual Studio desde el instalador del IDE y me generó la carpeta con los archivos correspondientes.

Answer (score 0):

Me pasó exactamente lo mismo al desplegar un nuevo ambiente local de desarrollo desde cero con los fuentes y la base originales.
Entonces fui a ver si las carpetas mencionadas estaban creadas y sí, existían.
Entonces repasé los pasos y me di cuenta de que le había dado UPDATE Model para restaurar la conexión a la base desde el modelo, **pero no había guardado** los cambios del modelo (el temor más grande en EF).
Simplemente al darle guardar al modelo (recientemente actualizado) automáticamente tomó el valor de referencia (desde el WebConfig).